# How to allow only to a specific ratio when taking photos in custom Android camera app?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In my app user need to take a picture in a ratio of 1:1 and it must be the back camera.

So is there a way to set the ratio to 1:1 only and disable switching to the front camera?

Here is a part of my code:

```
private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {

    ContentValues cValues = new ContentValues();
    cValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, "Photo");
    cValues.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DESCRIPTION, "Camera");
    imageUri = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, cValues);

    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);

    try {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
    catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
        // display error state to the user
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a crop option so that you can have the ratio of what you want

```
`private fun pickImage() {
    val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
    //to crop the image
    intent.type = "image/jpg"
    intent.putExtra("crop", "true");
    intent.putExtra("aspectX", 10);
    intent.putExtra("aspectY", 10);
    intent.putExtra("outputX", 396);
    intent.putExtra("outputY", 396);
    intent.putExtra("noFaceDetection", false);
    intent.putExtra("return-data", true);
    startActivityForResult(intent, imgcode)
}`
```

ActivityResult be like

` override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
//checking the request codes

```
    if (requestCode == 1111 && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        //converting to bitmap
        val bmp: Bitmap? = data?.getParcelableExtra<Bitmap>("data")
        img.setImageBitmap(bmp)`
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Could you please share the java version of the code too? So, crop option works after a photo is taken and it crops the photo to ratio that i want but it does not directly block the other ratio options right?

Comment: I don't do in java and there is not much difference in this code .. This is enough info for you to read and understand 90% of Java code if you know Kotlin: 1) Variable and function declarations start with the type instead of fun, val or var before the name. 2) Constructor calls have the new keyword before them when they are called. 3) Instead of : to show what a class extends or implements, the keywords extends or implements are used. 4) Functions that return nothing return void instead of Unit